# Cannot Reinstall Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, reinstall, reset

My aim here is to reinstall Windows 8 Pro either by resetting or reinstalling from physical media, however I run into problems whichever option I want to use.

**Resetting Windows 8 from PC Settings**

Everytime I try this I get a message stating, "There was a problem while resetting your pc". This happens if I try it from PC settings, boot options and from a recovery disk. When booting back into Windows I get a window that apparently checks for solutions but nothing happens.

**Reinstalling Windows from a media**

I upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 8 Pro using the Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant. I never got an ISO or disk. I have tried downloading an ISO from here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only, however when I type my serial number in all I get is a message stating, "The product key you entered is an upgrade key and can't be used to install Windows 8".

**Redownload via Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant**

This just tells me there is nothing to download in my area / country.

So as you can see, I am in quite a situation. Thanks.

Comment: Do you still have your original Windows 7 installation media and key?

Comment: Ever thought to raise a support request by phone at Microsoft? There are actually people working there who get paid to help you out.

Comment: Support expired after 90 days.

Comment: I might have it somewhere. Is it required to do a clean install?

Comment: @joshkrz  Microsoft still helps with product key issues.  If you give them your Win7 product key and win 8 they should either give you a new key or modify your existing one.

Comment: The Upgrade Assistant allows you to download an iso, that is the only legal way, to get a Windows ISO based on the license you now own.

Comment: @cybernard: It's not a product key issue so much as not having access to setup media.

Comment: @Karan You don't need the full version.  If you call Microsoft and say "I have an upgrade version of Win8, and I need to re-install it.  However, I don't want to have to re-install windows 7 first." I had the same issue from Vista to win 7. After giving them both product keys they gave me a new product key that turned it into a full install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worst case:

Download Windows 7 from here:

```
Windows 7 Home Premium x86  SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24208.iso
Windows  7  Home Premium x64 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24209.iso
Windows 7 Professional x86 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24280.iso
Windows 7 Professional x64 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24281.iso
Windows 7 Ultimate x86 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24394.iso
Windows 7 Ultimate X64 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24395.iso
```

Enter your Win 7 product key.
Make a DVD from the win 8 DVD you got, if you haven't already.
Put it in and upgrade it back to Win 8.

Now back everything up, so if you screw up you can restore this backup.